# Ember active link

Tags: ember.js

I have a route where I want to make a sibling route's link-to's active as well. I have tried using current-when in the link-to, but it's not working for me.

my routes are as follows

```
//projects
//projects/:project_id
//projects/:project_id/user/:user_id
```

When I navigate to //projects/:project_id route, the right link is set to active. I want the same link to be active on the //projects/:project_id/users/:user_id route.

My link-to in the parent //projects hbs template is

```
{{#link-to "projects.project" item.projectID current-when="projects.user" tagName="tr"}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it to initially work when the route is rendered by using an edited version of @ykaragol's helper function and link-to...

```
{{#link-to "projects.project" item.projectName active=(calculate-active 'projects.user projects.project' item.projectName) tagName="tr"}}


compute(params, hash){
var pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var pathProj = pathname[2];
var currRoute = this.get('currentRouteName');
var routes = params[0].split(' ');
if( ($.inArray( currRoute, routes) > -1) && (pathProj == params[1]) ){
  return true;
}
return false;
}
```

But it's not updating when I click on a different project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If routes don't have dynamic segments, it works as described in [docs](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_keeping-a-link-active-for-other-routes). I've tested it within [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2936b1a1eca85f3323cdfaa6ff8762b4?openFiles=templates.parent.child1.hbs%2C&route=%2Fparent%2Fchild2).

But I couldn't make it work while using dynamic segment. Please check [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9e8af96e4755b2f8ba255996c5a2aef3?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Fparent%2Fchild2%2F6). I suspect this maybe a bug. You can ask this question in [slack](https://www.emberjs.com/community/).

By the way, as a workaround, you can pass a boolean to the `currentWhen` property (as mentioned in [docs](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_keeping-a-link-active-for-other-routes)). So you can write a helper or a computed property to calculate it with a regex.

**Updated:**

As a second workaround, you can handle `active` property of `link-to` by yourself. Try [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/38c95e8bd5fc97396f1750d66eb8cca7?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Comment: That is a good idea on the workaround, but there is an existing bug that won't let me use a boolean value in a current-when  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12296

Comment: I've also tried using the didTransition action hook on the //projects/:project_id/user/:user_id route to manually (via jquery) add the active class to the div, but it isn't working either.

Comment: So this got me closer, but all project links are getting set to active when on the users page. Given that I have two dynamic sections in the URL, can you update the Twiddle to show how I'd incorporate that?

Comment: In the helper, observer currently listens to `currentRouteName`, switch it to the `routing.currentState`.

Comment: Instead of parsing it from address bar, you can use the `-routing` service. something like `this.get('routing.currentState.routerJsState.params.projects.project_id')`

Comment: @user6041966 did you test observing the `routing.currentState`?

Comment: I did. That fixed it. Thanks for your help!!